# OnePlus One stuck on boot animation after trying to root unlock bootloader and install TWPR

Tags: root, bootloader

I am a OnePlus One user since earlier this year and on day one I followed this [video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x7C9Rmk2RxQ) to root, unlock and install TWPR so that I could flash CM12 to get Android Lollipop on my OnePlus. I have recently brought my girlfriend a OnePlus One and tried to follow the same steps as it came running CM11 and couldn't find any over the air updates for the phone. I followed the same video up to booting the phone into TWPR. When holding down the Volume Down and the Power button until the OnePlus logo showed, the phone would just restart, cancelling my request to get into TWPR. Because of this I tried doing the process again and had the same issue, I have only done this once with my OnePlus and before this phone I have only had iPhones so I am new to this process.

I left the phone as I had to go out for the day and came back to it later. I tried following that video one more time but kept getting the same problem so I tried following a different video (can't find the video) and now I am faced with another problem on top of not being able to get into TWPR. The phone is now getting stuck on the CM11 boot animation when trying to boot up the phone making it unusable.

The one thing I remember doing differently in the second video was erasing some sort of cache thing in Windows Command Prompt and since going that far I can't seem to get the phone to boot up properly.

Can someone please help me not only fix this boot problem but also tell me how I can get into TWPR.

Matt

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't install CM12. You will rue the day you do because CM12's modem is A-W-F-U-L for OPO. Second, are you holding down the vol down button while you're restarting the phone? That can cause it to bootloop in some phones.

Have you managed to unlock bootloader?
Have you managed to install TWRP?

Depending on those questions will have very different answers on how to fix it.